# To find the Joint distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

$f(x,y)=(1+x^3\,y^3)/4 \quad \Big[(x,y)\in[-1,1]^2\Big]$

How to find the joint distribution of $f(x^2,y^2)$??

Well this one is completely new for me as I am a begginer. Any help would b appreciated.

Comment: The support for the pdf is required. $~$ Is it $(x,y)\in[-1;1]^2$?

Comment: Have you tried applying the Jacobian change of variables theorem?

Comment: @GrahamKemp is there another way??

Comment: Double integrate to find $\mathsf P(X^2<u,Y^2<v)$, then double differentiate with respect to $u,v$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Double integrate to find $\mathsf P(X^2\leqslant u,Y^2\leqslant v)$, then double differentiate with respect to $u,v$.

**Hint:** Actually, use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to avoid integrating and differentiating back.   It should then simplify greatly in just a few steps.

$\begin{split}\qquad f_{\small X^2,Y^2}(u,v)=~&\begin{vmatrix}\dfrac{\mathsf d^2 \mathsf P(X^2\leqslant u, Y^2\leqslant v)}{\mathsf du~\mathsf d v\hspace{16ex}}\end{vmatrix}\\[1ex]=~& \begin{vmatrix}\displaystyle\dfrac{\mathsf d^2 ~~~~~}{\mathsf d u~\mathsf d v}\int_{-\surd u}^{\surd u}\int_{-\surd v}^{\surd v} \dfrac{1+(xy)^3}{4}~\mathsf d y~\mathsf d x\end{vmatrix}\mathbf 1_{(u,v)\in[0;1]^2}\\[1ex]=~& \phantom{ \dfrac{1}{4\surd(uv)}\left(\dfrac{1+(uv)^{3/2}}{4}+\dfrac{1-(uv)^{3/2}}{4}+\dfrac{1-(uv)^{3/2}}{4}+\dfrac{1+(uv)^{3/2}}{4}\right)\mathbf 1_{(u,v)\in[0;1]^2}}\\ =~&\phantom{\dfrac{1}{4\surd(uv)}\mathbf 1_{(u,v)\in[0;1]^2}}\end{split}$